# prevent evaluation of non-matching case

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this case statement in a select:

```
CASE ('$5' = '')
  WHEN NOT FALSE THEN TRUE
ELSE
  ST_DWithin(latlong_g, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point($5::float, $6::float), 4326), $7, false) END
```

So if a parameter given to a prepare is empty, the case evaluates to true (for the enclosing and where it is used in a query), otherwise the else shall be executed.

Unfortunately as it seems the ELSE is evaluated by the pg parser and it chokes with the message:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""

Is there a way to prevent that error?

Edit: Full query for clarity:

```
SELECT addritems.*, 
       St_y(adresse.latlong), 
       St_x(adresse.latlong) 
FROM   adresse 
inner join addritems 
        ON addritems.adrcd = adresse.adrcd 
       AND addritems.plz LIKE Coalesce(Nullif($2, ''), addritems.plz) 
       AND CASE ( $3 = '' ) 
                 WHEN NOT FALSE THEN TRUE 
                 ELSE St_dwithin(latlong_g, 
                                 St_setsrid(St_point($3::FLOAT, $4:: FLOAT), 4326), 
                                 $5, FALSE)
           END
```

Comment: Are you using this a value for a `WHERE`, or for return a field in a `SELECT`? What is the full query? because a `CASE` **cant** return `TRUE` and `ST_DWithin` at same time. So maybe you want `NULL` for first one

Comment: I use this is in a `WHERE` .... `AND CASE` in a call to a sql library when quering PostGIS. The parameter $5 might be set to a numeric value or be the empty string so the whole `CASE`shall either evaluate to `TRUE` to become  `AND TRUE` or, if the parameter is set, call the `ST_DWithin` function. However the `CASE ELSE` part is evaluated even though the input is ''

Comment: Edit1: The `'`in the call to ST_Point are likely no to be used.

Comment: I stumbled on the same problem - ELSE is evaluated when it's not needed. Much more simple example for that: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/1737 . Can somebody clarify: is that PG bug or not? I checked PostgreSQL 10 (in fiddle) and PG 11 yet.

Comment: @JohnDoe see my updated answer , I tried to explain why that is failing

Answer (score 2):

How about using OR:

```
SELECT addritems.*, St_y(adresse.latlong), St_x(adresse.latlong) 
FROM  adresse 
inner join addritems 
  ON addritems.adrcd = adresse.adrcd 
  AND addritems.plz LIKE Coalesce(Nullif($2, ''), addritems.plz) 
  AND ( 
        $3 = '' 
        OR St_dwithin(latlong_g,St_setsrid(St_point($3::FLOAT, $4::FLOAT),4326),$5,FALSE)
      )
```

To answer alex from comment:

The reason there is: Postgresql when parse the query, it sees ( 1/0) as a constant and try to make it simpler by actually diving the numbers, whereas if you replace that with something that the value can't be evaluated in parsing step, it will be postponed to the execution time. For example if you replace (1/0) with (1/floor(random()), the query will run successfully, because the value of "random()" will be revealed at the time of execution.

```
SELECT 
    current_catalog
    ,current_catalog::text = 'test'
    ,CASE
        WHEN current_catalog::text = 'test' THEN 1  -- division by zero
       ELSE 1 / floor(random())
    END
```

Note: floor(random()) is always 0 since random() is between 0 and 1.

Comment: The OP question was about `CASE-WHEN-ELSE-END` statement. But anyway: can you explain how to cure such query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/1737 ?

Comment: @AlexYu  see my updated answer , I tried to explain why it fails

Comment: Hm. It seems you're correct. Such trick will solve my problem (I want to have an ability to add stoppers to SQL scripts). Although I'm not sure if that solve original OP problem. Anyway: Thank you!

Comment: Can you edit your answer a bit ? I mean "quey", "diving the numbers" and so on ;)

Comment: @AlexYu if you are trying to get an answer on your specific problem , please ask a new question. feel free to tag me there

Comment: @AlexYu I'm not following what you mean by adding stoppers

Comment: I accept your answer. You helped me to implement simple functionality: Let's say we have a lot of databases with similiar content. The goal is to create script that works on exact one database and stops on others. It's very simple to choose incorrect DB when using DBeaver for example. Simple solution - check `current_catalog` in CASE and do something illegal if it's not needed db. I first tried `1/0` in ELSE but that did not worked. Trick with `1/floor(random())` - is exactly what's needed.

Comment: Although I'm not sure is that what OP asked. But anyway it looks he solved his problem 5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write your CASE like this

```
CASE 
    WHEN ('$5' = '') THEN NULL  -- or -1 some other constant, 
                                -- I guess distance cant be negative.
    ELSE ST_DWithin(latlong_g, 
                    ST_SetSRID(ST_Point('$5'::float, '$6'::float), 4326), 
                    $7, false) 
END
```

If `NULL` work for you, also can use the default value from `CASE`

```
CASE 
    WHEN ('$5' <> '') 
    THEN ST_DWithin(latlong_g, 
                    ST_SetSRID(ST_Point('$5'::float, '$6'::float), 4326), 
                    $7, false) 
    -- NO NEED ELSE mean default to NULL.
END
```

**EDIT:** after your query you need

```
   AND (( $3 = '')  OR
        ( St_dwithin(latlong_g, 
                     St_setsrid(St_point($3::FLOAT, $4::FLOAT), 4326), 
                     $5, FALSE)
        ))
```

Comment: I use the `CASE` in a `WHERE`-clause so it should either evaluate to `TRUE`to match all rows, or, if the paramter $5 is set, call the function, which returns true or false.

Comment: I told you show me your full query. look like you want  `WHERE (('$5' == '') OR (condition filter))`

Comment: Full query provided

Comment: I stumbled on the same problem as OP and I have even simpler query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/1736   I suppose it's a bug in PostgreSQL - ELSE is evaluated always. Maybe you can clarify things? Am I mistaken?